# Angular & Firebase: How to pre-populate select input from lookup collection?

Tags: angular, firebase, select, angular-material

**Issue**: I am unable to pre-populate a select input with the existing value when the select options are populated from another lookup collection.

**Details**: The value attribute of the select input is the entire document object from my lookup collection (locations). When I save an event, I save two values from that object to my events collection (locationName and locationState). This makes it easier to show the location information when displaying details about the event.

**Demo**: Add an event by giving it a name and selecting an existing location. Then click on the event below to edit that event. Notice the name input pre-populates however the select input is blank.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firestore-check-if-value-exist-t9n8tz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem  is,

- the value you saved is not exists in lookup. Because, you saved as
  string '*location name*' but your look up is array of objects
  '*locations*.
- You saved *locationName* and *locationState*, but while syncing you are expecting *location*. which is not exists.

To solve,

in **edit-event.component.ts** file change

```
 this.updateEventForm.patchValue({
        name: e.name,
        location: e.location
      });
```

to

```
 this.updateEventForm.patchValue({
        name: e.name,
        location: e.locationName
      });
```

Then, we ne need to modify the angular comparison logic. Because, as I mentioned, now we are trying to compare *string* with *object*. So it wont match.

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [formControl]="updateEventForm.controls['location']" placeholder="Location" [compareWith]="compareFn" >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let location of locations | async" [value]="location">
        {{ location.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Notice `[compareWith]="compareFn"`

In component,

```
  compareFn(c1: any, c2: any):boolean{
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.name === c2 : c1 === c2;
  }
```

And here's the updated code,
https://angular-firestore-check-if-value-exist-gzwuke.stackblitz.io/event/5YcKMkTO3KH459Kpqzg6

---

Alternatively, You can also save the complete location object while saving (instead on *locationName* and *locationState*). So In edit, saved location object will be matched in lookup list.

Comment: Interesting, that worked great at setting the value on the input. However, when it sets the value, it is set as a string of `e.locationName` which is invalid since it's expected to be an entire object (the service then grabs the individual property value in the object). To recreate: edit an existing record, without changing the location value, click Update. Notice `Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field locationName)`.